# Change From name PHP mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a question

I have a php module that sends mail, and works fine, but I have a problem.

When I receive the mail in the From name I receive this SiteMessageadminpage@admin.com. What I want is to leave only the name.

I have this code

```
$email_from2="adminpage@admin.com";
    $headers .= 'From: Page.com' . $email_from2 . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $email_from2 . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Please help

Comment: You forgot a space between the from name and the address. But it sounds like that's not what you meant?

Comment: This is the problem with calling `mail()` yourself - it implies that you know RFC822 inside out, which most people don't, so it leads to problems like this. Do yourself a favour and [use a library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems sending with mail(), use the PHPMailer library:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer